# Контролы произвольной высоты, не растягивающие "строчку"

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать вот такой layout:

[image]

Смысл в том, что контролы расположены вертикально фиксированной высоты, но у некоторых слева есть связанный с ними контрол произвольной высоты. 
Делаю так: сначала идет панель с элементами `display: block` (вертикальная), внутрь кладу горизонтальную, в которую помещаю блок с фиксированной высотой и с произвольной.
Пробовал выставлять `vertical-align: middle`, но тогда эта "строчка" становится высокой и расстояние между основными контролами увеличивается. Как этого избежать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сверстал таблицей: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YSfhb/embedded/result/) | [source](http://jsfiddle.net/YSfhb/)

```css
table {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
tr {} 
td {
  height: 5em;
}
td > span {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 125px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
td > span.fixed-h {
  height: 25px;
}
td > span.adaptive-h {
  height: 3.3em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="fixed-h">FIXED</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="adaptive-h">ADAPTIVE</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="fixed-h">FIXED</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="fixed-h">FIXED</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="adaptive-h">ADAPTIVE</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="fixed-h">FIXED</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Пы.Сы.: CSS свойство "vertical-align: middle" работает только при "display: table-cell" (у ячеек таблицы по-умолчанию).*

Answer (score 0):

Задай фиксированный `line-height` и используй `inline-block`.